# How to undo an ssh-copy-id?

Tags: 10.04, ssh, hadoop

I have a 2 node hadoop cluster.

I ran this command on the master:

```
$ssh-copy-id -i /home/hadoop/.ssh/id_rsa.pub hadoop@192.168.1.1
```

**How can I undo this?** I would actually like to reassign the key.

`192.168.1.1` is the slave.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Identify the public key that you copied when you ran `ssh-copy-id`:

```
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

SSH to the server you copied the key to:

```
ssh hadoop@192.168.1.1
```

Edit the file `~hadoop/.ssh/authorized_keys` on `192.168.1.1` using your preferred editor, and delete the line containing your key.

Comment: Is there a way to do it more automatic why? Like `ssh-rm-id hadoop@192.168.1.1`

Comment: @S.R I'm not aware of a single command that automates this. In theory, you could "automate" it yourself with a little one-liner using `ssh` to run a `sed` command (or similar) to edit `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and remove the line. See https://superuser.com/questions/429954/command-to-remove-a-ssh-authorized-key-on-server

Answer (score 9):

If you have done a `ssh-copy-id` like:

```
remote='user@machine'
ssh-copy-id -i $remote
```

So you can access this remote machine without using a password:

```
ssh $remote
```

To undo it programmatically, you can script something like:

```
idssh=$(awk '{print $2}' ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub)
ssh $remote "sed -i '\#$idssh#d' .ssh/authorized_keys"
```

I use it in scripts I need to `scp` several files, so I ask only once for password.

Comment: This might be a bit dangerous: you are grepping for the _comment field_ of the key. It is an arbitrary string without any meaning and may be contained more than once. I'd grep either for the long `AAA....==` string (the actual key) or for the complete line from `id_rsa.pub`. But +1 for showing how to automate the removal of a key.

Comment: @PerlDuck you are right. It is much better to use the key ($2) itself than the third field. Thank you.

Comment: @Javi M. I encountered another issue. The forward slash used by default as the delimiter in sed was in my public key. As a result, I found it best to use a semicolon as the sed delimiter since it appears unlikely to show up in public key. To do this, it was necessary to first escape the character. I ended up with something like this: ```ssh $remote "sed -i '\;$idssh;{d}' .ssh/authorized_keys"```

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38829833/253576) is some information on which characters can end up in a public key.

Comment: Thanks @ccalvert. Based on your suggested comment I have approved chris-maes edition

Comment: I am unable to make an edit as it's a single character and changes require more than that.  I'm an Ubuntu noob, but I believe that the separator needs to be prefixed with the backslash \ character.  At least that was the only way I could get this to actually remove the key line.  So it should be `'\#$idssh#d'` instead.

Comment: @mle_ii thaks for you fix